# Extjs date column format

Tags: javascript, date, extjs, datepicker, date-format

i have date column with datefield editor. The problem is that while im editing column it displays the normal value for example `2013-02-05`, but when close editing it displays something like `Sat Jul 12 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (FLE Standard Time)`

My code:

```
{
    xtype : 'datecolumn',
    dataIndex : 'depreciationStartPeriod',
    header : 'Depreciation start period',
    sortable : true,
    id : 'depreciationStartPeriod',
    width : 134,
    editor : {
        xtype : 'datefield',
        format: 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
    }
}
```

store field:

```
{
    name : 'depreciationStartPeriod',
    type : 'String',
    dateFormat: 'c'
}
```

what the reasons could be?

**UPDATE**

in store it is also saved with wrong format for some reason, that's why it is being displayed in such format, but i don`t now the reason of that.

Comment: Would you mind preparing a jsfiddle for this? Someone might be more willing to really help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{
    xtype : 'datecolumn',
    dataIndex : 'depreciationStartPeriod',
    header : 'Depreciation start period',
    sortable : true,
    id : 'depreciationStartPeriod',
    width : 134,
    format: 'Y-m-d H:i:s', // <------- this way
    editor : {
        xtype : 'datefield',
        format: 'Y-m-d H:i:s',
        submitFormat: 'c'  // <-------------- this way
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out again. I had a same problem and i solved it a this way.

Comment: maybe it's because i'm using extjs 3.4? not the latest? Because this does not work for me

Comment: i have found the problem, it was because my other function which added grey colour to this column. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

You need to have your store field as a `date` type, not a `string`.  Because it is currently a string, ExtJS is converting it directly from `datefield.getValue().toString()`, which is what is giving it that full format your are getting.

Also note that even if you wanted to use a `string` for `type`, the word should be entirely lowercase (you currently have `String`).  Check out this link for the valid `type` params you can use: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-type

Comment: changing it to `date` format does not change anything, i get the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

try giving type in store as Ext.data.Types.DATE i had similar problem by changin the type to Ext.data.Types.DATE solved it